# Rails nested routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to build a forum while nesting the routes and I keep running into this error:

**undefined method `forum_threads_path' for**

I have nested my routes as so in my routes.rb file

```
 resources :forum_subjects do
    resources :forum_threads, module: :forum_subjects do
      resources :forum_msgs, module: :forum_threads
    end
  end
```

I am trying to call this using **form_for** in a partial of the **_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@forum_subject, @forum_thread] do |f| %>
```

My view files are also located in folders within the one main one:
**forum_subjects/forum_threads/forum_posts** where all the view files are also nested.

Comment: Your actual model name is `Forum` and `Thread` right? And also are they namespaced?

Comment: No they are not namespaced and it is forum_thread yeah

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is correct. Since, your forums_threads is nested inside forum_subjects you will not be able to call the forum_threads_path. You will be able to find out the correct method to call if you run the rake routes in the terminal by changing directory to your project. Ideally there will be a method called forum_subject_forums_threads_path.

Comment: I tried using form_for the way i did. I try to access forum_subject_forums_threads_path with the [@forum_subjects, @forum_threads] part. I am not using any direct urls because I am using a partial form to be rendered in different files.